# New XCode Template Equivalents

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, xcode4.2

I'm in the process of learning Objective-C for the iPhone and the biggest hurdle I currently have is that most of the old tutorials aren't based on ios5.  In general that's fine because I don't want to use storyboards yet until the adoption of ios5 picks up so the tutorials are fine if I ignore the garbage collection instructions.  However, the problem I'm running into is that most tutorials have you start out with a "Navigation-based Application" or a "Window based Application" and these no longer exist in XCode 4.2.

So my question is, if I'm trying to follow tutorials that use one of the above templates, which one of the new templates should I choose that will be closest to it?  There's a lot of great tutorials out there that I'd love to be able to utilize, and most of the ios5 ones deal with storyboards, not actually learning general development.

Thanks a lot for you time and help, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Window based applications you can find the equivalent here: http://www.trappers.tk/site/2011/06/16/mainwindow-xib/ (i've tried this and it works) or a ready-made download here: http://forums.bignerdranch.com/viewtopic.php?f=73&t=3336 .

Comment: Thanks, I'll check these out!

Answer (score 3):

Choose the Master-Detail Application template and you'll be fine.

Comment: I'll give this a shot and see if I can get them going.  Thanks a lot.