# What should I use instead of Window-based application template in Xcode 4.2.1?

Tags: ios, ios5, xcode4.2

I'm trying to follow along with some tutorials on the web on `Xcode` programming. Nearly all of them have an earlier version of `Xcode` than I do and the starting application templates are not the same. Most of them start with a Window-based application template. What is the equivalent in `Xcode 4.2.1`? Page-based or Single view or Empty or something else? Thanks much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're reading Big Nerd Ranch's IOS programming book then I would suggest checking out the following links:

http://forums.bignerdranch.com/viewtopic.php?f=74&t=3166
http://forums.bignerdranch.com/viewtopic.php?f=74&t=1817

I believe the Single View Application is probably what you are looking for, but you may need to make some modifications to get it working with your book.

The links above should be able to help you with that though.

The second link also contains a link to a zip file if you really need the window based application templates.

Comment: Great threads! Thanks for sharing. The second one was especially helpful. For those who are reading this post later, the most useful tidbits were:

"I believe 'Single View Application" in Xcode 4.2 + iOS sdk 5.0 is the same as "View Based application" in the book screenshot and 'Window based Application" which is used in the screenshot is probably called "Empty Application" in the new xcode 4.2 ide."

...and the link to download earlier versions of Xcode from [http://connect.apple.com].

Answer (score 1):

In 4.2 the new Empty Application Template provides you with just a delegate and a view, the functional equivalent of window based.

Comment: I don't think you get a xib file with this template. Better to go with a Single View Application, if working through demos as any mentioning Windows-based application will expect a xib.

Answer (score 1):

The folks at Big Nerd Ranch supplied a Template for the Window-Based Application which you can add to your Xcode 4.2 and restore the ability create from such a template.  It will be mostly identical to the template in previous versions of Xcode, at least for the purposes of doing exercises from the book.  Here's the link: 
[Window-Based Application template](http://forums.bignerdranch.com/viewtopic.php?f=73&t=3336)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use **Master-Detail Application** template. After creating a project your appDelegate will contain `UIWindow` instance.

```
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UINavigationController *navigationController;

@end
```

Comment: I saw a similar answer elsewhere on this site [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7902660/new-xcode-template-equivalents]. It completely confused me, because the icon for Master-detail shows something like the Mail interface, which isn't what I wanted at all. But after actually trying this, it makes sense and it works.